# ADO.NET DataRelations and many-to-many relationship

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net

I was really drawn in and fascinated by the DataRelation object for use in an ADO.NET DataSet to cache data from my database in an ASP.NET web application.  Unfortunately, I realized quite late, that I really have three DataTables.

- Users with a PK of UserID
- Groups with a PK of GroupID
- UsersInGroups a linking table with UserID and GroupID columns

Is it possible to load these three tables into a DataSet, add DataRelations, and then retrieve:

- All Groups
- All Users
- All Groups that contain a certain user (by UserID)
- All Users in a specific group (by GroupID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good reference from MS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6s958d6(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Awesome link!  Thanks!  Looks like what I need to do is create DataTables for the three tables I mention, and create DataRelations between Users and UsersInGroups and UsersInGroups and Groups.  Then to get all groups with a certain user, I use user.GetChildRows("Users_To_UsersInGroups"), and for each child row (in UsersInGroups) run userInGroup.GetParentRow("Groups_To_UsersInGroups") to get the Group info.